# angular js- MVC4 routing url modify

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, url, routes

I dont know why my url looks like "`http://localhost:5267/#!/test`" for MVC4 and angular js. (a hash tag followed by exclamation mark).

can anyone help me to correct this url like "`http://localhost:5267/#/test`".

Comment: try this `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`

Comment: Perfect. thanks Hadi.